# Does one have to keep the printed e-Visa on which the immigration agent wrote the visa expiry date?

Tags: visas, india

Upon entering India with an e-Visa (formerly known as tourist visa), the immigration agent writes  the expiry date of the visa on the printed e-Visa (not the one on the passport, but the one we're supposed to print from the e-visa website). Does one have to keep the printed e-Visa on which the immigration agent wrote the visa expiry date?

The printed e-Visa looks like this:

[image]

Comment: For your own safety, please reupload the Document with some other layer on top of the blur. I can read almost everything you tried to blur out.

Comment: @DaanvanHoek thanks, I took the image from Google. Blurring typically isn't good for hide information indeed.

Comment: Then everything is ok, was just worried that my eyesight had improved drastically =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was in India, they didn't write on my evisa. The passport stamp will provide the exact same information you described. However, you need to keep your visa with you wherever you go for the full extent of your stay which may be up to 60 days. After you arrive home you are free to discard your visa. Just save your visa number and the dates of travel in case you want to visit India again because you will need that information for the application process.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, definitely. It is a document that proves you are within the period of time allowed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to travel.SE! It'd great if you can expand on your answer, for example, how long is one expected to keep this document for - during their stay, for 10 years, or for as long as practically possible? It would also be great if you can provide some other source to substantiate the claim.

Comment: Wouldn't the stamp on the passport be enough to prove one is within the period of time allowed?